# PHP DocuSign API - Set carbon copies (email)

Tags: php, docusignapi, carbon-copy

I'd like to CC someone with the DocuSign PHP API. This is the code I have at the moment.

```
$all_cc = [];
$cc = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\CarbonCopy();
$cc->setEmail("email@domain.com");
$cc->setName("Bob Smith");
$cc->setNote("This is a note for the CC guy");
$all_cc[] = $cc;
```

Then I try to feed the above into the **setCarbonCopies** method of the recipients object.

```
$recipients = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients();
$recipients->setSigners($all_signers);
$recipients->setCarbonCopies($all_cc);
```

I've also tried passing **$cc** directly into **setCarbonCopies** but that also doesn't work.

Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE:**

So I got it to work by adding this line:

```
$cc->setRecipientId("XXX");
```

I've notice though that the email is only CC'd to the user AFTER the document has been signed. I would like to CC the user before it is signed. Not sure if that's possible.

Comment: What is the error or undesired behavior that you're seeing?

Comment: The exception that is caught comes back with this message: [400] Error connecting to the API (https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/XXXXXXX/envelopes). This is thrown when trying to create the envelope. The error only occurs when I starting messing with the CC stuff.

Comment: is the recipientId you set unique? (not the same as the signer)?

Comment: That's correct. The recipient ID is unique.

Comment: If you care to do so, you should answer your own question by posting the full solution as an answer, then marking it as accepted a couple days later. That way this perfectly functional solution won't look like an unanswered abandoned question to the SO community. It worked for me.